# iterator and hasNext() power implementation

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, iterable

I'm still learning java and I'm trying to implement an iterator interface that returns the power value of integers (10^1 = 10, 10^2 = 100 etc) and I'm having trouble with syntax

Comment: are you re-initializing your iterator in a loop?

Comment: no in the initialization block at the top near the class declaration

Comment: I think you need to show to show the calling code. I don't see the members being reset in any of this code.

Comment: hasNext() isn't supposed to modify any state of the iterator. Why are you incrementing currentPow in hasNext()?

Comment: The only way it could reset is if you instantiate a new powIterator each time you call it. We need to see the calling code.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You said something about a static block? Please don't describe code, but rather, include it in your question, removing irrelevant parts only ([mcve]).

Comment: i've added the calling code @Dakoda

Comment: I shouldn't increment in hasNext()? @JBNizet how should i increment then? does it do iit automatically?

Comment: You should go to the next element i next(). Not in hasNext(). hasNext() must tell if there is a next element. Read the javadoc.

Comment: but it's a sequence of integers how will it know to increment @JBNizet

Comment: It knows to increment because someone calls next(). What's the problem? See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/4299e66429d1874330fbc37e7514ee2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the hasNext() method must not change the value of "currentPow" member.
A correct implementation would be:

```
@Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
  return currentPow <= maxPow;  
}
```

The reason you keep getting the same result (10) is because you do not multiply a member of the class. 
You don't really need "index" member so instead define:

```
public class powIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{

  private int currentPow = 1; 
  private int currentResult = 1;
```

And now next() should look like this:

```
@Override
public Integer next() throws NoSuchElementException {

  if (index <= maxPow){ 
    index++;
    currentResult *= base;        
    return currentResult; 
  }
  else {   
    throw new NoSuchElementException();        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables inside your Iterator are not reset every time, you simply *don't update* them ever. So in the next run they are just the same.

As mentioned, you should probably not update `currentPow` inside `hasNext()`. As the name suggests it is just a check if there are more items. You should then move to the next step inside `next()`.

Maybe try something like this:

```
  private int currentPow = 1;

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
     return currentPow <= maxPow;  
  }

  @Override
  public Integer next() throws NoSuchElementException {
     if(currentPow > maxPow)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Power is above the maximum");

     int pow = (int) Math.pow(base, currentPow);
     currentPow++;
     return pow;
  }
```